# Keras ImageDataGenerator: why are the outputs of my CNN reversed?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to code a CNN which distinguishes between cats and dogs. 
I have set my labels such that dog:0 and cat:1, so I'm expecting my CNN to output a 0 if it's a dog and 1 if it's a cat. However, it is doing the opposite instead (giving a 0 when its a cat and a 1 for a dog). Please review my code and look where I went wrong. Thanks

I'm currently on python 3.6.8, using jupyter notebook (all the code inside is me copy-pasting different parts of the code from the jupyter notebook)

```
import os
import cv2
from random import shuffle
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, load_img, img_to_array
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dropout, BatchNormalization
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ReduceLROnPlateau
%matplotlib inline

train_dir = r'C:\Users\tohho\Desktop\Python pypipapp\Machine Learning\data\PetImages\train'
test_dir = r'C:\Users\tohho\Desktop\Python pypipapp\Machine Learning\data\PetImages\test1'
IMG_WIDTH = 100
IMG_HEIGHT = 100
batch_size = 32



######## THIS IS WHERE I LABELLED 0 FOR DOG AND 1 FOR CAT ##########
filenames = os.listdir(train_dir)
categories = [] 
for filename in filenames:
    category = filename.split('.')[0]
    if category == 'cat':
        categories.append(1)
    elif category == 'dog':
        categories.append(0)

df = pd.DataFrame({'filename':filenames, 'class':categories}) # making the dataframe

#### I SPLIT THE DATA INTO TRAIN AND VALIDATION DATASETS ####
df_train, df_validate = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.25) # splitting data for train/test
 # need to reset index for both dataframs so imagedatagenerator works properly
df_train = df_train.reset_index(drop=True)
df_validate = df_validate.reset_index(drop=True)

print(df_train['class'].value_counts())
print(df_validate['class'].value_counts())

len_training = df_train.shape[0]
len_validate = df_validate.shape[0]
print('{} training eg, {} test eg'.format(len_training, len_validate))



#### CREATE IMAGE DATA GENERATORS ####
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
                               shear_range = 0.2,
                               zoom_range = 0.2,
                               horizontal_flip = True)
# our train_datagen generator will use the following transformations on the images
validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(df_train, 
                                                    train_dir,
                                                    target_size=(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT),
                                                    batch_size=batch_size,
                                                    x_col='filename',
                                                    y_col='class',
                                                    class_mode = 'binary')

# generator = ImageDataGenerator(*args).flow_from_dataframe(dataframe, directory, target_size,
# batch_size, x_col, y_col, class_mode)
# your dataframe shoudl be in the format such that x_col = features, y_col = class/label
# binary class mode since output is either 0(dog) or 1(cat)

validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(df_validate, 
                                                   train_dir,
                                                    target_size=(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT),
                                                    x_col='filename',
                                                    y_col='class',
                                                    class_mode='binary', 
                                                  batch_size=batch_size)

########## BUILDING MODEL ############
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3,3), input_shape=(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, 3)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), input_shape=(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, 3)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(128, (3,3), input_shape=(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, 3)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Flatten()) # remember to flatten conv2d to dense layer
model.add(Dense(256))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))

model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid')) 
# since we have only 1 output with range [0,1], we use sigmoid
# if there were n categories, use softmax

# binary_crossentropy since output is either 0,1
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

earlystop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=3) # stops learning if val_loss doesnt improve
learning_rate_reduction = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_acc', 
                                            patience=2, 
                                            verbose=1, 
                                            factor=0.5, 
                                            min_lr=0.000001) 
# reduces learning rate if val_acc doesnt improve
callbacks = [earlystop, learning_rate_reduction]

##### FIT THE MODEL #####
epochs = 50
model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                   steps_per_epoch=len_training//batch_size,
                   verbose=1,
                   epochs=epochs,
                   validation_data=validation_generator,
                   validation_steps=len_validate//batch_size,
                   callbacks=callbacks) # fitting model


######### PREDICTING #############
output_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(df_output,
                                                   outputdir,
                                                   x_col='filename',
                                                   y_col=None,
                                                   class_mode=None,
                                                   target_size=(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT),
                                                   shuffle=False,
                                                   batch_size=batch_size)
predictions = model.predict_generator(output_generator, 
                                      steps=np.ceil(len_output/batch_size))
df_output['probability'] = predictions
df_output['label'] = np.where(df_output['probability'] > 0.5, 'cat','dog')
df_output.head()
```

The CNN gives the opposite of the correct answer, and when reversing the outputs, I get the expected results (correct identification and accuracy).
I know that just changing the line `df_output['label'] = np.where(df_output['probability'] > 0.5, 'cat','dog')` to `df_output['label'] = np.where(df_output['probability'] < 0.5, 'cat','dog')` settles the problem, but that's not helping me figure out why the output of the CNN is reversed.

Comment: Can you include the code where you are defining your dataframe `df`?

Comment: Edited the code above to include it. It was just a ````df = pd.DataFrame({'filename':filenames, 'class':categories}) ```` @sdcbr

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The cause of your issue is subtle. I'll illustrate what is going on with a toy example. Suppose we instantiate a datagenerator with the following code:

```
# List of image paths, doesn't matter here
image_paths = ['./img_{}.png'.format(i) for i in range(5)] 
labels = ...  # List of labels

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['filename'] = image_paths
df['class'] = labels

generator = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=df, 
                                                    directory='./',
                                                    x_col='filename',
                                                    y_col='class')
```

The ImageDataGenerator expects the `class` column in the dataframe to contain string labels associated with the images. Internally, it will map these labels to class integers. You can inspect this mapping by calling the `class_indices` attribute. After instantiating our generator with the following list of labels:

```
labels = ['cat', 'cat', 'cat', 'dog', 'dog']
```

the `class_indices` mapping will look as follows:

```
generator.class_indices
> {'cat': 0, 'dog': 1}
```

Let's instantiate the generator again, but change the label of the first image:

```
labels = ['dog', 'cat', 'cat', 'dog', 'dog']
# After re-instantiating the generator
generator.class_indices
> {'dog': 0, 'cat': 1}
```

The integer encoding of our classes is swapped, which suggests that **the internal mapping of labels to class integers depends on the order in which the different classes are encountered**.

You are mapping `cat` to 1 and `dog` to 0, but the ImageDataGenerator interprets these as label strings and maps them to integers internally.

**Now what happens if the first image in your directory is a cat?**

```
labels = [1, 0, 1, 0, 0] # ['cat', 'dog', 'cat', 'dog', 'dog']
# After re-instantiating the generator
generator.class_indices
> {1: 0, 0: 1}  # !
```

And this is the source of your confusion. :) To avoid this, either:

- use 'cat' and 'dog' in the label column of your dataframe and let the ImageDataGenerator handle the mapping for you
- pass a list of classes to the `classes` argument in the call to
  `flow_from_dataframe` to specify the mapping explicitly.

Comment: If I passed the training set through the generator, and say that the classes mapped are `{'dog':0, 'cat':1}`, and I were to pass a new dataset in, with a cat being the first image. Will cat then be mapped to 0 or 1?

Comment: Good question. I wonder if this is intended behaviour. I'd have to look in the source code but I don't really have time now. It's probably safest to explicitly specify the mapping yourself.

Comment: Over the past two weeks, a couple of bugfix versions of keras_preprocessing have been released, and this behavior has changed. See https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/releases